# Rich Data Table Highlighting a column in JSF and at a time only one highlighted column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, datatables

In my rich `DataTable` there is a column which have command link, when i click on one link it should be highlighted and if click on different link , first one should become normal and otherlink should be highlighted.

`Function Jquery

```
function highlightSingleRow(col) {
    jQuery(col).parent().parent().find('tr').removeClass('dashBoardPowerOutP1');
    jQuery(col).parent().addClass('dashBoardPowerOutP1');
}
```

Style class

```
.dashBoardPowerOutP1{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Rich:`DataTable` column where i need changes:

```
     <rich:column sortBy="#{boardList.ci}" styleClass="#{boardList.dashBoardStyle}">
                    <a4j:commandLink actionListener="#       {globalCommandCenter.getWidgetDetails}" reRender="widgetPanel,knowledgeDetailsPanel,knowledgeDetailsTable,knowledgePanelLoader,ticketDetailsPanel,ticketDetailsTable,ticketDetailsPanelLoader"
                                            style=" font-family:Calibri; FONT-SIZE: 10px;color: #F5857C; " 
                                            onclick="Richfaces.showModalPanel('loaderImage1');" 
                                            oncomplete="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('loaderImage1');loadRemainingWidgets();highlightSingleRow(this);">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{boardList.ci}" ></h:outputText>
                                            <f:attribute name="ciName" value="#{boardList.ci}" />
                                            **<a4j:support event="onRowClick"  />**
                                        </a4j:commandLink>  
                </rich:column>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : remove `dashBoardPowerOutP1` class for all `td`s inside parent `tr` and then apply same class to the parent `td` of clicked link.

```
function highlightSingleRow(col) {
    jQuery(col).closest('tr').find('.dashBoardPowerOutP1').removeClass('dashBoardPowerOutP1');
    jQuery(col).closest('td').addClass('dashBoardPowerOutP1');
}
```